# understanding the following statement: If $K$ is a Field, then it's a Euclidean ring:

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let's recall that:

- An integral domain $A$ is a **Euclidean ring** if $\exists$ a function $\delta: A\setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ s. t: $\forall a,b (\neq 0) \in A, \delta(a) \leq \delta(a.b)$ and $\forall a,b   (\neq 0) \in A, \exists q,r$ s.t $a=bq+r$ with $a=0$ or $\delta(r) < \delta(b)$

Now I'm given a few examples of Euclidean ring:

- $\mathbb{Z}$ (with $\delta(n) = |n|$)
- Now they also say that if $K$ is field, then it's a euclidean ring **And that, I don't understand**.

Comment: Try any constant function $K^* \to \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: There is a typo: $a=bq+r$ with $r=0$ or ... But the statement is  a sort of joke. In a field, if $b\not=0$ we can write $a=bb^{-1}+0$ and no matter what $\delta$ is we are happy.

Comment: @ancientmathematician what do you mean? isn't $bb^{-1} = e$? so that would be true only if $K = {e}. Or do I just don't understand you explanation?

Comment: That was a typo, he/she meant $a= bb^{-1}a+ 0$

Comment: You're right, I should have written $a=b(b^{-1}a)+0$.

Comment: More commonly it's called an euclidean domain :P

Answer (score 0):

Let $\delta(x)=p$ for any $p\in\Bbb N$, then the first property is clearly satisfied. Then for
$$a=bq+r$$
we set $q=b^{-1}a$ and $r=0$. and we have it satisfied.